# Centos7 R xgboost package install error : can't install package ‘xgboost’ up to 1.1.1.1

Tags: r, installation, centos7, xgboost, r-server

I got an following error message while installing xgboost package on R :

```
C++ compiler cannot create executables
```

To solve this problem, updating gcc & cmake :
gcc : 4.8.5 → 8.5.0
g++ : 4.8.5 → 8.5.0
CMake : 2.8.12.2 → 3.18

After this update, I can only be installed up to 1.1.1.1.
But I need a version of xgboost package 1.7.3.1 or higer.

Still got an error message...

```
> packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xgboost/xgboost_1.2.0.1.tar.gz"
> install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘/home/subinji33/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xgboost/xgboost_1.2.0.1.tar.gz'을 시도합니다
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 971402 bytes (948 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 948 KB

* installing *source* package ‘xgboost’ ...
** 패키지 ‘xgboost’는 성공적으로 압축해제되었고, MD5 sums 이 확인되었습니다
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking Backtrace lib... 
checking for backtrace in -lexecinfo... no
checking endian... 
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
Error in .shlib_internal(args) : 
  C++14 standard requested but CXX14 is not defined
* removing ‘/home/subinji33/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xgboost’
* restoring previous ‘/home/subinji33/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xgboost’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpkrU2VY/downloaded_packages/xgboost_1.2.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

My sessioninfo :

> sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=ko_KR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=ko_KR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=ko_KR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=ko_KR.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=ko_KR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=ko_KR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=ko_KR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shapviz_0.9.2     xgboost_1.1.1.1   lattice_0.20-38   ggplot2_3.4.2     lubridate_1.8.0   stringr_1.5.0     data.table_1.14.8
 [8] tidyr_1.2.0       dplyr_1.1.2       glue_1.6.2        pool_1.0.1        RPostgreSQL_0.7-5 DBI_1.1.3        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0    listenv_0.9.0       purrr_0.3.4         splines_3.6.0       colorspace_2.1-0    vctrs_0.6.3         generics_0.1.2     
 [8] yaml_2.3.5          utf8_1.2.3          survival_2.44-1.1   prodlim_2023.03.31  rlang_1.1.1         later_1.3.1         pillar_1.9.0       
[15] withr_2.5.0         foreach_1.5.2       lifecycle_1.0.3     plyr_1.8.8          lava_1.7.2.1        timeDate_4022.108   munsell_0.5.0      
[22] gtable_0.3.3        future_1.33.0       codetools_0.2-16    parallel_3.6.0      class_7.3-15        fansi_1.0.4         Rcpp_1.0.11        
[29] scales_1.2.1        ipred_0.9-14        parallelly_1.36.0   digest_0.6.29       stringi_1.7.12      grid_3.6.0          hardhat_1.3.0      
[36] cli_3.6.1           tools_3.6.0         magrittr_2.0.3      tibble_3.2.1        future.apply_1.11.0 pkgconfig_2.0.3     MASS_7.3-51.4      
[43] Matrix_1.5-1        gower_1.0.1         rstudioapi_0.13     iterators_1.0.14    globals_0.16.2      R6_2.5.1            rpart_4.1-15       
[50] nnet_7.3-12         nlme_3.1-139        compiler_3.6.0
```

gcc & Cmake version :
[gcc & Cmake version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwWRt.png)

Comment: Not sure if it would help, but is there a way to update R?